# Private helper functions in Python classes are giving "global name <name of method> is not defined"

Tags: python, oop

I am creating a class which holds a dict, and has some methods to extract information based on the data in the dict. Each key points to a list of strings. Each string in the list is of the form `name(data).`

I am very new to programming in Python and have mainly used Java previously. I have created a couple of private helper functions that are to be used for in my public methods. Here is an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
def _getItemName(item):
    str = ""
    for c in item:
        if c!= '(':
            str += c
        else:
            break
    return str
```

This method is then used in several public methods, like in this example:

```
def getCertainItemsByName(self, key, name):
    foundItems = []
    for item in self.itemMap[key]:
        if _getItemName(item) == name:
            foundItems.append(item)
    return foundItems
```

This is giving me an error equivalent to "global name "_getItemName" is not defined. I realize I could just declare the method outside of the class, but the method is class-specific so that's not something I want to do. What is the best to do this?

Comment: you can use @staticmethod

Comment: `_getItemName(self,item)` and  use `self._getItemName`

Comment: `_getItemName` needs to receive `self` as its first argument.

Comment: I don't want to pass it self as an argument because it isn't an instance method. I guess I will make it static, but that isn't very appealing to me either because it is a method that is only to be used inside the class, so it seems unneccesarily clunky to need to prefix the class name when calling it inside the class definition.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your question you are missing `self`;

```
def _getItemName(self, item):
    str = ""
    for c in item:
        if c!= '(':
            str += c
        else:
            break
    return str

def getCertainItemsByName(self, key, name):
    foundItems = []
    for item in self.itemMap[key]:
        if self._getItemName(item) == name:
            foundItems.append(item)
```

You should look at `static method`, `class method` and `instance method` in Python.

> Static methods are a special case of methods. Sometimes, you'll write
>   code that belongs to a class, but that doesn't use the object itself
>   at all. For example:

```
class Pizza(object):
     @staticmethod
     def mix_ingredients(x, y):
         return x + y

     def cook(self):
         return self.mix_ingredients(self.cheese, self.vegetables)
```

For more, you can visit [here](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was already aware of the possibility of making this static but I guess I was just looking for a more elegant way of doing this, similar to how it is done in Java.